# how to use limit with an input from a procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, limit

I want to use pollNo in limit, but it get an error:

> error :Script line: 4 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'pollNo,1 )as A join
>   poll_data on A.id=poll_data.poll_id;
>
> END' at line 6

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `prj`.`ret_poll` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `prj`.`ret_poll` (IN pollNo int)
BEGIN
select * from
(select * from poll limit pollNo,1 )as A
JOIN poll_data
on A.id=poll_data.poll_id;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you using? I think this is fixed in 5.5 and forward, but prior versions need a workaround, since they want integer constants or prepared statements.

So, prior to 5.5 you should be able to do something like the following;

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `prj`.`ret_poll` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `prj`.`ret_poll` (IN pollNo int)
BEGIN
PREPARE STMT FROM "select * from (select * from poll limit ?,1 ) as A join poll_data on A.id=poll_data.poll_id";
SET @start = pollNo;

EXECUTE STMT USING @start;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can read more about it here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` requires an integer as input, not a column name.  To do what you're talking about requires dynamic queries.

Here's a [forum post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,27979,30437) that talks about executing dynamic SQL in MySQL.

Comment: pollNo is int :  (IN pollNo int)

Comment: I realize that pollNo contains an INT, but that's not the point.  LIMIT requires a _literal_ INT, not a variable or column name.